# React - set controlled input value from the Redux Store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, controlled-component

I'm dispatching a redux action on `onChange` event on an input to add to some "answers" array on the Redux state.
Everything works fine and the Redux store gets updated, but the issue is when setting the `input` value to reflect the change in the Redux store, it gives me an error in the console that says ...

`Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type number to be controlled.`

Here's a codesandbox to demonstrate the issue ...

https://codesandbox.io/s/controlled-input-issue-p2k74

How can I make the `input` to be controlled, but via the Redux store, not the local state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to an input to be controlled, just pass a value every time to `value` prop of input element like, change this

**QuestionAnswerInput.js**

Change the input component to

```
  <input
    type="number"
    value={getInputValueFromStore(answers, questionId) || ""}
    onChange={e => handleAddNumericalAnswer(e)}
  />
```

For more about controlled components refer [this](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-controlled-components) article